# Variable Counts and tracking changes

Tags: r, count, row

I have a list of students and I need to see how many of them are transferred to a different college.

The first entry represents the student's "home school", if the college entry stays the same for all the semesters, then the student did not transfer. If for one of the semesters the college is different then the student did transfer. I would like Transfer to be set as a dichotomous variable (0,1).

Here is my trial data.

```
Semester <-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
Student <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),c(5,4,5,3,2,2,5,6,4,4))
College <- rep(c("ATC","CCTC","DTC","FDTC","GTC","HGTC","MTC","NETC"),c(5,6,4,5,6,4,5,5))
test.dat1 <- cbind(Semester,Student, College)
```

I need to make a table that looks like the following:-

[image: Table]

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize the semester line didn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `group_by` each student, and then consider the home school to be the first college for that student.

The transfer column would be the numeric logical result of whether the home school and new school are different.

**Edit**: The new school is the first school attended that is different than the home school, if there are multiple colleges attended.

```
library(tidyverse)

test.dat1 %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  group_by(Student) %>%
  summarise(Home_School = first(College),
            New_School = if_else(n_distinct(College) > 1, first(College[College != first(College)]), Home_School),
            Transfer = +(Home_School != New_School))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Student Home_School New_School Transfer
   <fct>   <fct>       <fct>         <int>
 1 A       ATC         ATC               0
 2 B       CCTC        CCTC              0
 3 C       CCTC        DTC               1
 4 D       DTC         FDTC              1
 5 E       FDTC        FDTC              0
 6 F       FDTC        GTC               1
 7 G       GTC         GTC               0
 8 H       HGTC        MTC               1
 9 I       MTC         NETC              1
10 J       NETC        NETC              0
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a question, what if the new-school is not the last slot for a given student?

Comment: Yes, that could be the case that I need to account for,

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!